# Checking if a user is a member of a SP Group within a SharePoint Add-on

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, spgroup

I have a SharePoint Add-on for Office 365. It is currently a SharePoint Hosted app and I would like to keep it that way.

My Problem is I am trying to find out if a user is a member of a group either directly or through an AD group. I'm currently querying the user, using the API, for a list of groups they are a member of but this only returns groups that the have been added directly to.

I have seen the workaround on [Check users group membership via REST API using AD-Groups in SP-Groups](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/134509/check-users-group-membership-via-rest-api-using-ad-groups-in-sp-groups) but I don't have control over the SharePoint groups

Do anyone know if it is possible to check if a user is a member of a SharePoint group when they are added via an AD group using the REST API or JSOM?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122139/check-if-current-users-belongs-to-sp-group-using-javascript-client-side-object-m

Answer (score 0):

Try this to check the current user group

```
    <script src="https://c4968397007.dc07.loc:2000/sites/DeveloperSite/Style%20Library/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 function TempMethod()

 {

 //alert('Loaded');

 }

 function CheckCurrentUserMembership() {

 var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

 this.currentUser = clientContext.get_web().get_currentUser();

 clientContext.load(this.currentUser);

 this.userGroups = this.currentUser.get_groups();

 clientContext.load(this.userGroups);

 clientContext.executeQueryAsync(OnQuerySucceeded);

 }

 function OnQuerySucceeded() {

 var isMember = false;

 var groupsEnumerator = this.userGroups.getEnumerator();

 while (groupsEnumerator.moveNext()) {

 var group= groupsEnumerator.get_current();

 if(group.get_title() == "Administrator Group") {

 isMember = true;

 alert('Success');

 break;

 }

 }

 OnResult(isMember);

 }

 function OnQueryFailed() {

 OnResult(false);

 }

 $(document).ready(function ($) {

 ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(TempMethod, "SP.js");

 SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', TempMethod);

 //ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(TempMethod, "SP.ClientContext");

 CheckCurrentUserMembership();

 });

 </script>
```

I Hope it will help you, Change it to as per you requirement.

Comment: Thanks for this, unfortunately, this return the same as the REST API and only get the groups the user is a direct member of.