# How can I fetch only AD groups not SharePoint Groups with REST API or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, jsom, active-directory, groups

I want to fetch the a user's membership and AD groups (Not SharePoint Groups).

So, how can I fetch the data using REST API or JavaScript?

Comment: This might help you. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/134509/check-users-group-membership-via-rest-api-using-ad-groups-in-sp-groups

Answer (score 0):

The following REST call will GET all AD Groups that are being used in the site without iterating through the SharePoint Groups:  `/_api/web/siteusers?$filter=PrincipalType eq 4`.